# Could not load file or assembly or its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm following the tutorial as shown in the link below:

[Creating an Entity Framework data model for ASP.NET MVC application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

But while running the application, the following exception comes:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Vag_Infotech' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My web.config file is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CollegeDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=VInfotech;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<contexts>
  <context type="Vag_Infotech.DAL.CollegeDbContext, Vag_Infotech">
    <databaseInitializer type="Vag_Infotech.DAL.CollegeDatabaseInitializer, Vag_Infotech"></databaseInitializer>
  </context>
</contexts>
```

CollegeDbContext Class:

```
namespace Vag_Infotech.DAL
{
public class CollegeDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public CollegeDbContext()
        : base("CollegeDbContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

}

The exception comes in the StudentController.cs class:

[image]

Comment: I didn't make it yet because in the tutorial it is specified as such to make a dll. @Tobberoth

Comment: Is your namespace named Vag_Infotech? It seems to have problems finding it. Can you post the code of your CollegeDbContext class? Or maybe the initializer code from the DAL folder since that seems to be the key issue.

Comment: @Tobberoth yes. I made a mistake while creating the application i entered the name of application Vag Infotech.

Comment: Hmm, CollegeDbContext looks fine to me.. can you use Find in Files to search for Contoso and see if there's anywhere you missed to change ContosoUniversity to Val_Infotech?

Comment: looking at it @Tobberoth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great News,

I solved my problem. I initialized my DatabaseInitializer from the `Global.asax` file. Take a look on the code below:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        Database.SetInitializer(new CollegeDatabaseInitializer());
    }
}
```

I simply initialize my `CollegeDatabaseInitializer()` in the `Application_Start()`. But please note that remove the `<contexts>` from the `Web.Config`file. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what caused this issue because all I did was copy paste text from the tutorial.  Anyways this worked for me as well.  I wonder if it has anything to do with running parallels on a Mac?

Comment: @Nimit Joshi It worked for me but why it was a problem of the Context tag in the web.config ?

Answer (score 0):

Run Developer CommandPropmpt for VisualStudio 2012 as Administrator and then run the command over it.